# leetcode heaters incorrect output

Tags: javascript

I was doing leetcode heater question.

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/heaters/

On 23/30 input on submit, I am getting incorrect output but I am unable to figure out why,

23rd input

```
[282475249,622650073,984943658,144108930,470211272,101027544,457850878,458777923]
[823564440,115438165,784484492,74243042,114807987,137522503,441282327,16531729,823378840,143542612]
```

Expected output is: `161834419` but my current output is `181367746`

Here is my code

```js
const a = [282475249,622650073,984943658,144108930,470211272,101027544,457850878,458777923]
const b = [823564440,115438165,784484492,74243042,114807987,137522503,441282327,16531729,823378840,143542612]

function findClosest (house, heaters) {
// if only one heater in array of heaters, subtract it with house number to get the difference and return it 
if (heaters.length === 1) return Math.abs(house - heaters[0]) 
  const middleIndex =  Math.floor((heaters.length - 1)/2)
  // if middle heater is equal to house, heater exist on that house number, difference would be zero
  if (house === heaters[middleIndex]) return 0 
  // heater on the leftside and rightside of the middle Heater, if leftside and rightside does not contain any elements (undefinned) then middle would be the left and right most element
  const left = heaters[middleIndex - 1] || heaters[middleIndex] 
  const right = heaters[middleIndex + 1] || heaters[middleIndex]
  // if the left side heater location is greater than current house location, we need to move to left
  if (left > house) { 
   return findClosest(house, heaters.slice(0, middleIndex))
  }
    // if the right side heater is less than current house, we need to move to right
  if (house>right) {  
    return findClosest(house, heaters.slice(middleIndex + 1, heaters.length))
  }
 // finding diff b/w left and right index and returing the ones with lease distance
  const leftDiff = house - left 
  const rightDiff = right - house 
  if (leftDiff < rightDiff) return leftDiff 
  else return rightDiff
}


const findRadius = (houses, heater) => {
  let maxIndex = 0
  houses.sort((a,b) => a-b)
  heater.sort((a,b) => a-b)
  for (let i=0; i<houses.length; i++) {
    const currentIndex = findClosest(houses[i], heater)
    if (currentIndex > maxIndex) maxIndex = currentIndex // if the current returned distance is the highest, set that as maxIndex
  }
  return maxIndex
}


console.log(findRadius(a, b))
```

#### What I am doing

- Finding closest left and right radius from house
- Which one is closer is compared with current maximum radius, if it is greater than that becomes current maximum radius

Can someone help me in finding mistake in my algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the middle element as well. That is the condition that is missing in your case.

Updated code would be:

```
function findClosest (house, heaters) {
// if only one heater in array of heaters, subtract it with house number to get the difference and return it 
if (heaters.length === 1) return Math.abs(house - heaters[0]) 
  const middleIndex =  Math.floor((heaters.length - 1)/2)
  // if middle heater is equal to house, heater exist on that house number, difference would be zero
  if (house === heaters[middleIndex]) return 0 
  // heater on the leftside and rightside of the middle Heater, if leftside and rightside does not contain any elements (undefinned) then middle would be the left and right most element
  const left = heaters[middleIndex - 1] || heaters[middleIndex] 
  const right = heaters[middleIndex + 1] || heaters[middleIndex]
  // if the left side heater location is greater than current house location, we need to move to left
  if (left > house) { 
   return findClosest(house, heaters.slice(0, middleIndex+1))
  }
    // if the right side heater is less than current house, we need to move to right
  if (house>right) {  
    return findClosest(house, heaters.slice(middleIndex + 1, heaters.length))
  }
 // finding diff b/w left and right index and returing the ones with lease distance
  const middleDiff = Math.abs(house-heaters[middleIndex])
  const leftDiff = house - left 
  const rightDiff = right - house 
  return Math.min(middleDiff, leftDiff, rightDiff)
}


function findRadius  (houses, heater) {
  let maxIndex = 0
  houses.sort((a,b) => a-b)
  heater.sort((a,b) => a-b)
  for (let i=0; i<houses.length; i++) {
    const currentIndex = findClosest(houses[i], heater)
    if (currentIndex > maxIndex) maxIndex = currentIndex // if the current returned distance is the highest, set that as maxIndex
  }
  return maxIndex
}
```